# Angular CLI productive build error using globalize

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, globalize

I'm trying to localize an **angular 6+** application with **globalize**.

It builds and works fine in development mode, but unfortunately building it for production mode: "**ng build --prod**" I get this  error: "**ERROR in Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined**".

The source code for localization is written in a service called "*german-language.service.ts*". If I comment out the content of the "*initLagnuage*" method, it builds without error.

Globalize and devextreme-cldr-data is installed. Also tried cldr-data.

Has someone and idea how to solve that problem?

Edited:

The error does not appear if one comments out "resolveJsonModule: true" in tsconfig.json.

Seems it is related to angular bug: TypeScript resolveJsonModule feature is broken when compiling with AOT #25456

german-language.service.ts

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import deMessages from 'devextreme/localization/messages/de.json';
import Globalize from 'globalize';
import 'devextreme/localization/globalize/number';
import 'devextreme/localization/globalize/date';
import 'devextreme/localization/globalize/currency';
import 'devextreme/localization/globalize/message';
import deCldrData from 'devextreme-cldr-data/de.json';
import supplementalCldrData from 'devextreme-cldr-data/supplemental.json';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GermanLanguageService {

  constructor() { }

  initLanguage() {
    Globalize.load(
      deCldrData,
      supplementalCldrData
    );
    Globalize.loadMessages(deMessages);
    Globalize.locale('de');
  }
}
```

The app configuration is as following:

tsconfig.json

```html
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/typings.d.ts"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "paths": {
      "globalize": [
        "node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize"
      ],
      "globalize/*": [
        "node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/*"
      ],
      "cldr": [
        "node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr"
      ],
      "cldr/*": [
        "node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```html
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "x.x.x.x",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.9",
    "@ngx-pwa/local-storage": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/devextreme": "^16.2.1",
    "@types/globalize": "^0.0.34",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "devextreme": "^18.1.4",
    "devextreme-angular": "^18.1.4",
    "devextreme-cldr-data": "^1.0.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "globalize": "^1.4.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^6.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

app.modules.ts

```html
...

export class AppModule {
  constructor(language: GermanLanguageService) {
    language.initLanguage();
  }
```